# How to Label Graph Edges with their weights

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

**Warning!** I posted the question when Mathematica v 8.0 was the coolest kid. The bug has been solved as of version 9.0.1

[`The help for EdgeLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeLabels.html) states:

[image]

However:

```
CompleteGraph[4,
 EdgeWeight -> Range@6,
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Name",
 EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

Results in:

[image]

So, no Edge Labels ... I guess it is a bug.

I used a nasty construct like:

```
adj = {{\[Infinity], 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, \[Infinity], 2, 2, 2}, 
       {1, 2, \[Infinity], 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, \[Infinity], 2}, 
       {1, 2, 2, 2, \[Infinity]}};

WeightedAdjacencyGraph[adj,
    VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
    EdgeLabels -> 
     MapThread[Rule,{EdgeList@#,AbsoluteOptions[#, EdgeWeight]/.{_ -> x_}-> x}], 
    GraphHighlight -> FindEdgeCover[#]]  
                                        &@ WeightedAdjacencyGraph[adj]
```

[image]

Better ideas?

Comment: Have you checked to see if it works using an adjacency matrix with the weights as the numbers in the matrix? I have a notebook (at home I think) that shows how to create weighted graphs with line thicknesses that are proportional to weights - a very popular presentation of data in my field.

Comment: Yes, it's at home. I can't help you for another nine hours, sorry :)

Comment: @Verbeia Thanks! I can wait, indeed!

Comment: @belisarius & the four letter word: `Graph` unfortunately still has some serious problems, be cautious and verify verify verify ... `Graph[]` objects occasionally end up in a corrupted state causing some functions to either give a wrong result or crash.  I've encountered problems with removing vertices and isomorphism testing in particular.

Comment: @Szabolcs I seldom use the Graph functionality, and each time I've to navigate trough the complexities of choosing among the disjoint implementations in Mma. I really hope they will get it settled in v9!

Comment: Interestingly, the EdgeLabels doc page on my 8.01/win7-64 version does NOT include the "EdgeWeight" value.

Comment: @belisarius  Seems like the problem lies with `EdgeWeights` rather than `EdgeLabels`.  (You may have already realized that. Your `MapThread` essentially generates weights on-the-fly.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a regular `GraphPlot`, you will need a slightly more complicated solution using `EdgeRenderingFunction` ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeRenderingFunction.html)). Suppose you have an adjacency matrix where the elements are also the (directional) weights.

```
lilnums = {{0, 2., 1., 3., 0, 6.}, {0, 0, 1., 2., 0, 0}, {1., 8., 0, 2., 0, 
 2.}, {10., 13., 7., 0, 0, 10.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {4., 1., 1., 2.,
 2., 0}}
```

Here are some labels for the vertices, supposing you are drawing network diagrams for international inter-bank exposures (the original has a lot more countries!).

```
names = {"AT", "AU", "CA", "CH", "CL", "ES"}
```

The following does what you need. The tricks are the reference back to the adjacency matrix using the parts of `#2` inside the part specification, to reference the correct elements of `nums`, and the `Mean[#1]` to locate the label at the midpoint of the edge. The slot `#1` seems to hold the coordinates of the vertices.

```js
GraphPlot[lilnums, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .04], 
 Black, Text[names[[#2]], #1]} &), 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({AbsoluteThickness[2], Red, 
 Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[#1, 0.05], Black, 
 Text[Round@ Abs[(lilnums[[#2[[1]], #2[[2]]]] + 
   lilnums[[#2[[2]], #2[[1]]]])], Mean[#1], 
  Background -> Yellow]} &), VertexLabeling -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 600,  
  PlotLabel -> Style["Plot Label", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Arial"]]
```

[image]

Comment: (Pedantic point, probably).  Am I correct in thinking that for weights greater than 1 this plot contains multiple edge labels (and edges) each placed one-on-top of the other, and it that OK? (It possibly is).  For printing purposes, say, will each be rendered in exactly the same place?  (I have had similar problems with edge labelling in another field, hence the interest)

Comment: @TomD - I don't think so. The plot is the same if you instead have `Sign[lilnums]` as the first argument, and/or if the option `MultiedgeStyle -> None` is used. Timings are the same, too.

Comment: @Verbeia.  Thanks for the clarification.  I missed that point.

Comment: Check chat to see how I did the syntax highlighting

Answer (score 5):

EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight" still doesn't work in 8.0.4 and no longer seems to be in the documentation. However, here is one solution that does work:

```
lilnums = {{0, 2., 1., 3., 0, 6.}, {0, 0, 1., 2., 0, 0}, {1., 8., 0, 2., 0, 2.},
  {10., 13., 7., 0, 0, 10.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {4., 1., 1., 2., 2., 0}}
names = {"AT", "AU", "CA", "CH", "CL", "ES"};
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[names, lilnums /. {0 -> \[Infinity]}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Name" , ImagePadding -> 15];
SetProperty[g, EdgeLabels -> MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, 
  {EdgeList[g], PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]}]]
```

Comment: This works just fine. Using the same technique I modified the EdgeStyle so that the lines thickness is proportional to the edge weight. Just set this additional property: `EdgeStyle -> MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {EdgeList[g], AbsoluteThickness[#] & /@ (1 + 3*Rescale[PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]])}]`

Answer (score 4):

**`EdgeLabels` works fine. `EdgeWeights` does not.**

It may already be obvious from Belisarius' second example that the problem lies with `EdgeWeights` not `EdgeLabels`

Here's some additional evidence. `EdgeLabels` very gladly displays a variety of labels correctly. But when you ask mma to display `"EdgeWeights"`, it incorrectly displays 1's, no matter what you've stored there.

```
CompleteGraph[4, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name",
 EdgeLabels -> {
   UndirectedEdge[1, 2] -> "hello", 
   UndirectedEdge[1, 4] -> "goodbye", UndirectedEdge[2, 3] -> 55, 
   UndirectedEdge[3, 4] -> \[Pi]/2, 
   UndirectedEdge[4, 2] -> 
   "\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(26\)]\)(-1\!\(\
   \*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(i\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \
   \(n - i\)]\)", UndirectedEdge[1, 3] -> {a, b, c}}]
```

[image: EdgeWeights.png]

The bug is not unique to `CompleteGraph`.   `Graph` and `GridGraph` have the same problem.

Comment: In fact all Graph unctions share the bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The solution is easy. Upgrade to V 8.0.1 :)

At least that is what I have and it works there. (windows 7)

[image]

Btw, I do not know if the labels on the edges are correct, but at least it does 
put them on the figure, unlike your image).

Comment: I get the same output in 8.0.1 on a Mac OS X, but I don't think the weights should be 1 in every case, given the `Range` construct in his example.

Comment: @belisarius This is what I get too, but I agree with Verbeia that the numbers on the edges seem to be incorrect.

Comment: @Nasser Very strange indeed!  `EdgeWeights` do not display properly for `Graph` either (in 8.0.1). Try: `Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 4}, 
 EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]`